# JavaScript, Jasmine, hide disabled jasmine specs

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'd like to hide the disabled jasmine specs when I run chosen tests. I'll have lot's of tests, so I wouldn't like to scroll down after each refresh to reach the tests which are at the bottom.

Is there any option in jasmine that allows it? I've went through the docs but didn't find anything.

Comment: I would like to do the same. Version 1.3 would hide the specs that weren't run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a design decision by pivotal as documented by this issue.

https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/issues/510

**Here is the fix from a comment in the issue.**

In jasmine-html.js, add a function to recursively determine if a result node has any active specs:

```
function hasActiveSpec(resultNode) {
  if (resultNode.type == "spec" && resultNode.result.status != "disabled") {
    return true;
  }

  if (resultNode.type == 'suite') {
    for (var i = 0, j = resultNode.children.length; i < j; i++) {
      if (hasActiveSpec(resultNode.children[i])) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in the summaryList function, just run that filter for suites:

```
// ...
var resultNode = resultsTree.children[i];
if (resultNode.type == "suite") {
  // Don't display inactive suites
  if (!hasActiveSpec(resultNode)) {
    continue;
  }

  // var suiteListNode = ...
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to modify the Jasmine source, you can also add a hook like this (my example assumes jQuery is present):

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
    jasmineDone: function () {
        $(".disabled").parents(".suite").hide();
    }
});
```

See http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running tests via Karma, there is a spec reporter plugin that you can configure to ignore various things.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-spec-reporter

https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-spec-reporter-2

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to hide a pending test. But you can add the next style to your test to hide the pending test.

```css
.pending {
  display: none;
}
```

You can see a working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/B5GMmvyXMxEH2SAFSm2M?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

Taken from the jasmine intro page...

> Suites and specs can be disabled with the xdescribe and xit functions,
>   respectively. These suites and any specs inside them are skipped when
>   run and thus their results will not appear in the results.

Comment: I believe he means they are skipped using the querystring. http://localhost/Tests?spec=Logs

Comment: For example http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html?spec=A%20spec you'll see all specs are shown even though only a few are run.

Comment: I see "**Ran 9 of 70 specs - run all
9 specs, 0 failures**"
and it seems to only have the 9 of them, could you clarify what I'm looking for here that is out of the ordinary?

Comment: With version 1.3 you would not visually see the 61 disabled specs. Now with 2.0 you visually see all 70 specs disabled or not. Contrast the previous link with http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html?spec=A%20spec